# libVLC not initializing on Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL 2.0)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, libvlc

I installed libvlc-dev via apt and it looks like it compiled fine as it can fine the headers and link with the libraries. The issue is when calling

```
libvlc_new(0, NULL);
```

It always returns a NULL (which is an error).

I tried this exact same project on windows, had the headers, linked the libraries, and also had a plugins folder that I needed to put into the root of the project; that worked beautifully. I don't know if Ubuntu or other Linux flavors has a requirement for a plugin folder at the root though.

Note this is Ubuntu in WSL 2.0; SDL works fine here and I can see a window showing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, fixed this. The other solutions mentioned a plugins folder for windows. Similar plugins are needed for linux. The easiest way to get them is to just do `sudo apt-get install vlc`. Then start your app and it should just work.

Other solutions would be to compile VLC yourself using the guide on their website.